# multiplying many numbers, but stopping at zero

Tags: optimization, multiplication

Suppose one has a function, prod(x), that returns the product of a sequence of numbers, x.

If the number of operands in x can be arbitrarily large, how might one think about reducing the time to compute the product of x by ceasing multiplication when zero is encountered? Is this something that mature compilers and interpreters already do?

If one is writing one's own prod(x) function, what is the best approach? Does it ever make sense to do something like `if 0 in x then return(0) else multiply(x)`?

For example, if `x = 1,0,3,4,...,-4,9`, one shouldn't need to continue multiplying past the second term, right?

Comment: I am really not sure what your actual question is? Is it "how to find if there is a zero value in my list of integers"... since the whole multiple a sequence of numbers is fairly arbitrary (read "uncommon"). If so, they yes you can optimise your method by check if there is a zero list value. I seriously doubt compilers have such an optimise check since multiplying an array of integers is probably not an intrinsic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: Compiler optimizations are mostly done on the given source code.  You're talking about optimization on run-time data, which compilers (normally) won't do.  This means that you have to write these optimizations yourself.

In this case: You can indeed stop when there's a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Any multiplication with 0 returns 0, so you'd check if there's a 0 in a sequence and just return 0.

Comment: Apologies if this I am being dense: does this mean that you agree with something like the conditional check I suggested in my question?

Comment: That would be the case, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Since the multiplication operation commutes, you can evaluate the terms in any order. If you were to have a sorted sequence of numbers, you could simply see if the first item is zero.

Comment: For sure sorting will burn much more cycles than a linear search through the list (until 0 is encountered).

Comment: Ok. Since the first zero encountered in the list would be a sufficient exit condition, should one generally roll one's own linear search to stop at the first instance, or is this generally how `A in B` operations work?

Comment: You are quite right, but cycling though a list would use more on an already sorted list. Perhaps the numbers come ascending order! :)

Comment: Generally the operation of checking inclusion in a set would just check each item in turn until either a match or the end is reached.

Comment: @S.Spencer The example list is not sorted.